# js: Better way to iterate through a nested object?

Tags: javascript

If I want to get a list of just the `types` of cars for this data:

```
let items = [
      {
         magnet: [
            true
         ],
         cars: [
             {
               type: "BMW"
             }
         ],
         name: "Roby"
      },
      {
         magnet: [
            false
         ],
         cars: [
             {
               type: "Mercede"
             }
         ],
         name: "Max"
      }
    ];
```

Is there a more efficient way than mapping through once like this?  I feel this isn't great because I'm making the assumption there is 1 item in the `cars` array.

```
items.map(x => {
   return x.cars[0].type
})
```

Comment: So what do you expect it to look like if there is more than one?

Comment: just an Array of Strings of all cars

Comment: I wouldn’t be concerned about performance before writing the code. Consider only optimising if it becomes a problem

Comment: `items.flatMap(item => item.cars.map(car => car.type))` ?

Comment: so two loops. push to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no more efficient way than to loop through all objects and their `.cars`, but of course there's a more correct way than to assume that each object has exactly one car.

The most appropriate helper method is [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), to be used either as

```
const cars = items.flatMap(item => item.cars);
const brands = cars.map(car => car.type);
```

or in one go

```
const brands = items.flatMap(item => item.cars.map(car => car.type));
```